# How does sklearn cross_val_score use kfold?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am new to machine learning and am trying to understand `cross_val_score` uses Kfold to split the data to k folds.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
cv_results =cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kf)
```

I know `kfold` splits the data but I tried printing it out

```
dataset = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6],[7,7,7],[8,8,8]]
kf =  KFold(n_splits=2)
print kf

>>> KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
```

It doesn't show the k folds but then how does `cross_val_score` get all the folds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call  `Kf.split(dataset)` to actually split the data. [Click here to see how KFold works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063014/what-does-kfold-in-python-exactly-do)

Just to make it clear, `KFold` is a class and not a function.

`kf = KFold(n_splits=2)` creates an object of KFold. 
and `print kf` will just print out the class object.

and when you call`cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kf)` you are passing the object `kf` to cross_val_score function where `kf.split(X_train)` would be called to split `X_train`  into 2 folds. `Y_train` would also be splitted similarly.

Comment: Thanks for  breaking it down for me to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
generator = kf.split(dataset)
for train, test in generator:
    print "*" * 20
    print "Training Data:"
    for i in train:
        print dataset[i]
    print "Test Data:"
    for j in test:
        print dataset[j]
```

kf.split(dataset) returns a generator. Iterating through the generator would give you all the folds

Comment: We are not passing the k folds to the cross_val_score function. Just the KFold  object. I mean, this does help if you want to see all the folds created by KFold.split() function

Comment: Thanks, I got the K folds, now how do I pass it to cross_val_score?