# Unsure about the purpose of get_n_splits and why it is necessary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I'm following a [kernel on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/serigne/stacked-regressions-top-4-on-leaderboard) and came across this code:

```
n_folds = 5

def rmsle_cv(model):
    kf = KFold(n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42).get_n_splits(train.values)
    rmse= np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(model, train.values, y_train, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv = kf))
    return(rmse)
```

I understand the purpose and use of KFold and the fact that is used in `cross_val_score`. What I don't get is why `get_n_split` is used. As far as I am aware, it returns the number of iterations used for cross validation i.e. returns a value of 5 in this case. Surely for this line:

```
rmse= np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(model, train.values, y_train, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv = kf))
```

cv = 5? This doesn't make any sense to me. Why is it even necessary to use `get_n_splits` if it returns an integer? I thought [KFold returns a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306633/how-does-sklearn-cross-val-score-use-kfold) whereas `get_n_splits` returns an integer.

Anyone can clear my understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought KFold returns a class whereas `get_n_splits` returns an integer.

Sure, `KFold` is a class, and one of the class methods is `get_n_splits`, which returns an integer; your shown `kf` variable

```
kf = KFold(n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42).get_n_splits(train.values)
```

is not a `KFold` class object, it is the result of the `KFold().get_n_splits()` *method*, and it is indeed an integer. In fact, if you check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold.get_n_splits), `get_n_splits()` does not even need any arguments (they are actually ignored, and exist only for compatibility reasons with other classes and methods).

As for the questioned utility of the `get_n_splits` method, it is never a bad idea to be able to query such class objects in order to get back their parameter settings (on the contrary); imagine a situation where you have multiple different `KFold` objects, and you need to get their respective number of CV folds programmatically in the program flow.