# How does batch size affects number of data splitted in folds?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

am working on an audio classification problem. am using the **urbansound8k** data set that contains **8732** audio.
I know that kfold is equally splitting data into k groups. each group will be used for testing and the rest will be used for training.

so if k=4, each group will contain **2,183** data. however, this result is far away from my own result

```
batch_size = 1
num_folds =4
no_epochs = 10

kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=False)

for train, test in kfold.split(features, labels):

  
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(no_classes, activation='softmax'))
  



  model.compile(loss=loss_function,
                 optimizer=opt,
                 metrics=['accuracy'])

  history = model.fit(features[train], labels[train],
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=no_epochs,
              verbose=verbosity,
              validation_split=validation_split,shuffle=False)
```

this code has these results with k=4 :
-**5239** per fold when using batch size = 1 
-**1048** per fold, batch size = 5
-**524** per fold, batch size = 10

am not understanding whats the relation between these two parameters: batch size and number of data in a fold.

am ready to share my whole code if required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does KFold in python exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063014/what-does-kfold-in-python-exactly-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are interested in the relation, they are, ignoring integer rounding, *inversely proportional*, i.e.

```
batch_size * number_of_data_in_fold = some_constant
```

Comment: how this relation is applied to my results?
1 * 5239 = 5239 so where is the 8732?

Comment: If you run model.fit on N items with batch size equal to B, the epoch will go through ceil(N/B) steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood now. So the number which epoch iterates on is how much the weights will be updated right?

Comment: The number of *steps* inside an epoch tells you how *often*, not much, will the weights be updated.